# ontransitionend not firing/attaching but addEventListener works

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Here is a reduced test case:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('test');
document.body.appendChild(div);
window.setTimeout(
  function() {
    div.style.boxShadow = '0 0 100px blue';
    div.ontransitionend = function() {
      console.log('transition end');
    };
    div.onclick = function() {
      console.log('click');
    };
  }, 100);
```

```css
div.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
}
```

Clicking on the div correctly triggers the `onclick` message, but the end of the transition does not trigger the 'transition end' message. Changing the event handler to this makes it work:

```
div.addEventListener('transitionend', function() { console.log('transition end'); } );
```

Why the difference between inline and `addEventListener`?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontransitionend), `ontransitionend` should work as I've written it, and searching around, Chrome does support it unprefixed (in fact I recall using it before with no problems). It's worth noting that the example shown on that MDN page doesn't work (doesn't display the "zooming" and "done" text) for me in Chrome.

Comment: I did edit your code to a live snippet, but for me it works (on  FF 63)

Comment: It seems that chrome only allows to set global prefixed handler  `window.onwebkittransitionend = function(e) { console.log('transition end', e.target); };` I mean by using direct assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer is that Chrome for some reason [does not support `ontransitionend` or several other transition events](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=868224&q=ontransitionend&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), even though I could've sworn I used them before...

Firefox runs my test case and MDN's test case correctly.